# Installing matplotlib / basemap on Azure Databricks

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, azure-databricks

Working on POC with netCDF(.nc) files.  Would like do some visualisation and while trying to install `Basemap` having some issues.

As per the pre-requisites, got `numpy` and `matplotlib`  installed.

`geos` is already installed

When installing `basemap` from git `%sh pip install pip install --user git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git` getting below error.

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git
  Cloning https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-w20pcpms
  Running command git clone -q https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.git /tmp/pip-req-build-w20pcpms
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /databricks/python3/bin/python3.7 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-w20pcpms/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-w20pcpms/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-req-build-w20pcpms/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-w20pcpms/
    Complete output (18 lines):
    checking for GEOS lib in /root ....
    checking for GEOS lib in /root/local ....
    checking for GEOS lib in /usr ....
    checking for GEOS lib in /usr/local ....
    checking for GEOS lib in /sw ....
    checking for GEOS lib in /opt ....
    checking for GEOS lib in /opt/local ....

    Can't find geos library in standard locations ('/root', '/root/local', '/usr', '/usr/local', '/sw', '/opt', '/opt/local').
    Please install the corresponding packages using your
    systems software management system (e.g. for Debian Linux do:
    'apt-get install libgeos-3.3.3 libgeos-c1 libgeos-dev' and/or
    set the environment variable GEOS_DIR to point to the location
    where geos is installed (for example, if geos_c.h
    is in /usr/local/include, and libgeos_c is in /usr/local/lib,
    set GEOS_DIR to /usr/local), or edit the setup.py script
    manually and set the variable GEOS_dir (right after the line
    that says "set GEOS_dir manually here".
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your [runtime version](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/supported.html) you may be pointing at the wrong version of python (I'm assuming python 3) with your pip commands. Also, if you're installing python packages through pip inside of a notebook environment you're going to have a bad time. The best way to install through pip on a cluster is to use an [init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html).